# Core Data - memory usage: my app crashes

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data, memory-management, loops

My question is about core data and memory usage. I have used core data before, but this time the amount of data is higher and this made me realise that there was much more to know.  I have seen that there are several other similar posts and I got interesting information from them, but after applying it my apps still crashes. I have been dealing with this issue for a week now. Somebody please help.

Basically I have three subsequent similar  loops of 64, 15, and 17 iterations respectively. They work fine on simulator. Tested on a couple of iPads  they get memory warnings and they crash at the same iteration (number 34 of the first loop). Tested on iPad 2 it will crash at number 14 of the second loop. Instruments shows a memory usage of about 1.5 MB both live and overall. There are leaks for a few KB.

The loops perform the following (code below)

- Execute a fetch with core data
- For every record take a parameter stored as a row property attribute (String)
- Call a procedure which takes that parameter and which returns data (about hundreds of KB)
- Store these data in another property attribute (Transformable) of the same row

Pretty common task isn't it?

Now, since I got into memory issues, I tried to use the all the known (by me) tools at my disposal, which are:

- release owned objects asap
- create autorelease pools and drain them asap for not owned objects
- save context asap
- turn objects into faults asap

After applying all these techniques I got an exciting result: the app crashes at the exactly same point as before.

Here it is the code.

```
- (void) myMainProcedure {
    [self performLoop1];
    [self performLoop2];  // Similar to loop1
    [self performLoop3];  // Similar to loop1
}
- (void) performLoop1 {
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSAutoreleasePool * myOuterPool;
    NSAutoreleasePool * myInnerPool;

    NSManagedObjectContext * applicationContext = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    [applicationContext setUndoManager:nil];


    NSEntityDescription * myEntityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityName"
                                               inManagedObjectContext:applicationContext];
    NSFetchRequest * myFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [myFetchRequest setEntity:myEntityDescription];

    NSString * column = @"columnName";
    NSPredicate * aWhereClause = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                  @"(%K = %@)", column, [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
    [myFetchRequest setPredicate: aWhereClause];

    myOuterPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSArray * myRowsArray = [applicationContext executeFetchRequest:myFetchRequest                                                                     
                                                              error:&error];
    NSMutableArray * myRowsMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    [myRowsMutableArray addObjectsFromArray: myRowsArray];
    [myOuterPool drain];
    [myFetchRequest release];

    EntityName * myEntityRow;
    int totalNumberOfRows = [myRowsMutableArray count];

    myOuterPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < totalNumberOfRows; i++) {

            myInnerPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
            myEntityRow = [myRowsMutableArray objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString * storedSmallAttribute = myEntityRow.smallAttribute;
            UIImageView * largeData = [self myMethodUsingParameter: smallAttribute];
            myEntityRow.largeAttribute = largeData;
            [myRowsMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];

            [applicationContext save:&error];
            [applicationContext refreshObject:myEntityRow mergeChanges:NO];
            [myInnerPool drain];
            [largeData release];
    }
    [myOuterPool drain];
    [myRowsMutableArray release];
}

- (UIImageView *)  myMethodUsingParameter : (NSString *) link { 
    UIImageView * toBeReturned = nil;
    NSURL *pdfURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:link];
    CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
    CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, 1);
    CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageRect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();   
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context,pageRect);
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, pageRect.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, - 1);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh); 
    CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    UIImage *imageToBeReturned = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    CFRelease(pdf);  
    toBeReturned = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageToBeReturned];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return toBeReturned;
}
```

- Please note that

  - The mutable array was introduced as a (apparently useless) strategy to
    have objects released sooner
  - Pools have been added ad part of the same strategy
  - The statement about interpolation quality was the only one to improve
    the situation (say, to move the crash
    a little bit forward)
  - Retain count for managed objects within the cycle ranges from 6 to 10
    (?) I know that rc is not a valuable
    information but still, I made a test
    and I found out that I could send 
    multiple release messages to managed
    objects before forcing the app to
    crash for this. But the point is that
    I am not supposed to release an
    object I don't own, am I? ....
  - The entity upon which the request is set has got also some
    bidirectional relationships with
    other entities, but still, is this
    relevant?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you returning and storing an UIImageView instead of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should get a fresh look at your problem.
There are many ways to deal with Core Data that are much simpler than your approach.
Creating class files for your Core Data entities may help you.
Also, when you are saving your files, you should seriously evaluate each objects necessity and whether it can be done a better way.
In your case, I would offer two suggestions:

---

For each PDF URL,

- a.Assign a unique identifier.
- b.Save this unique identifier in your
  core data store.
- c.Add url to a queue    for a
  background process that creates
  your PDF (background process will
  allow the user to keep working while 
  the PDFs are being generated. You
  could update your delegate on
  progress or create a temporary image 
  that is replaced when the PDF is
  created.)
- d.Save the image in your    app
  directory (or photo library)    using
  the unique identifier as a    name.
- e.When needed, load the image    from
  disk into a UIImageView or
  whatever appropriate.

---

For each PDF URL,

- a.Draw the PDF.
- b.Get UIImage representation
- c.Convert to PNG NSData
  (UIImagePNGRepresentation(image))
- d.Save NSData in CoreData.
- e.Load NSData and convert to UIImage
  when needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you are right, this I need to get a fresh look at this, but I don't seem to find the way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you are right, I need to get a fresh look at this, but I don't seem to find the way. By the way, the first suggestion sounds as a good idea, even if I don't have experience in multithreading. The second suggestion is more or less what I am trying to do, even if there is no conversion to NSData. Now let's assume to choose the second approach. We need to fetch some records from core data, then to update each of them setting a large NSData in an attribute. How could this loop be arranged to prevent memory issues? Could you post any code or code-like?

Comment: I think what might really help you is to read some good foundational materials on Core Data. You need to learn about how Core Data allocates and stores information, how it retrieves it, etc. Here's a good tutorial to get you started: